# Unable to use batch with special characters

Tags: batch-file

Hello I would like to know why this `é` blocks me from renaming, deleting etc.

How do I get around this `é`

del "BMW Coupé"

Comment: What type of encoding did you use to save your batch file? What is the codepage you are using in your batch file? What is your default codepage? Do you have any more files in your directory with a name beginning with `BMW Coup`? If you save your batch file ANSI encoded in codepage 1252, and change the codepage to 1252 in your batch file, I cannot see any reason whay it would not delete, subject to you using appropriate options `/A` and `/F` and the required privileges to delete the file.

Comment: Thank you. I have many files with that over that letter and characters, and for some reason a simple move or del does not respond, when I delete that letter, everything works great, I tried `del "BMW Coupe`.txt"` and it failed, but I manually removed that letter and it worked.. so weird